# Append column to text file with prefix of file names

Tags: linux

I have various files which contain only one column and I would like to add a second column which contain as rows the names of the prefix of the files:

Example:

file1_phone.txt looks like:

```
A
B
C
```

file2_phone.txt looks like

```
D
E
F
```

Output:

file1_phone.txt

```
A file1
B file1
C file1
```

file2_phone.txt

```
D file2
E file2
F file2
```

I wrote this loop in linux:

```
for f in *.txt; do
    b="${f%%_phone.txt}"
    awk -v RS='\r\n' 'BEGIN { OFS = " " } {print $0, "$b"}' "${f}"  > "${f}".new
done
```

However, it seems it will give this output:

Output:

file1_phone.txt looks like

```
A $b
B $b
C $b
```

file2_phone.txt looks like

```
D $b
E $b
F $b
```

Comment: I do not get your result, `$b` is not added on each line but at the end of the result

Comment: sorry, basically $b is added to each files in the second column

Comment: yes, but strangely I do not get that but for instance `A\nB\nC\n $b\n` (using C/C++ way to indicate newline)

Comment: because it seems that {print $0, "$b"} is printing $b in each column but I want the file extension to be added

Comment: I am using bash shell

Comment: I did with bash and sh, same result. Is the duplicate link help you ?

Comment: hmm... I looked at the duplicate link but does not seems to help me

Comment: sorry, yes, it did

Comment: for f in *_random30.samples; do b="${f%%_random30.samples}"; awk -v RS='\r\n' 'BEGIN { OFS = " " } {print $0, "'$b'"}' "${f}"  > "${f}".poplables; done

Comment: the "$b" is supposed to be " '$b' "

Comment: yes, this is what the duplicate link says ;-)